# Read through File find string Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I have a log file that i need to go through and find certain strings that do not match and write them out to the log. The code works until the problem arises where it duplicates the last value which is not needed. The code is here:

```
echo off 
set LogFile=log.out 
set LogFileSuccess=logFileSuccess.log
set FileName=testali.log
set lastline=
set currentline=


FOR /F "delims= " %%i IN (%FileName%) DO (SET currentline=%%i & CALL :process)

:process 
echo %currentline% | findstr /i "AD\System_ES_COG_RMT_D ??? =====" || echo Name Not Identified: %currentline% >> %LogFile%
```

and the log file is here:

```
Name Not Identified: 1796   Th:Pseudo   Idle    -   -   -   -    
Name Not Identified: 8572   Th:DynamicConfig    Idle    -   -   -   -    
Name Not Identified: 8008   AD\Kaif,    
Name Not Identified: 9332   AD\Mayekar,    
Name Not Identified: 5544   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 8952   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 6460   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 1796   Th:Pseudo   Idle    -   -   -   -    
Name Not Identified: 8572   Th:DynamicConfig    Idle    -   -   -   -    
Name Not Identified: 8008   AD\Kaif,    
Name Not Identified: 9332   AD\Mayekar,    
Name Not Identified: 5544   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 8952   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 6460   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 1796   Th:Pseudo   Idle    -   -   -   -    
Name Not Identified: 8572   Th:DynamicConfig    Idle    -   -   -   -    
Name Not Identified: 8008   AD\Kaif,    
Name Not Identified: 9332   AD\Mayekar,    
Name Not Identified: 5544   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 8952   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 6460   AD\Velusamy,    
Name Not Identified: 6460   AD\Velusamy,
```

The last Value is duplicated. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Any reason to not just use grep?

Answer (score 1):

After the `FOR` line, the batchfile continues with the next line (`:process`)

Just put an `exit /b` or a `goto :eof` between those two lines:

```
FOR /F "delims= " %%i IN (%FileName%) DO (SET currentline=%%i & CALL :process)
exit /b        <<<<<< here
:process
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I thought the FOR loop would stop running after the last line was read.

Comment: yes, your FOR loop DOES stop. But then the batchfile continues with the next line.